# regex with tabs \t

Tags: regex, elixir

I am trying to apply a named regex into a string which has its fields splitted by tabs but cant figure out how.

```
test = "2018-06-16T07:03:23.813056Z\thello\tworld"
Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<foo>)\\t(?<hello>)\\t(?<world>)/, test)
nil
```

Tab is a special character in the doc http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.7.4/lib/stdlib-1.16.4/doc/html/regexp.html so I am not sure if can be done like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern, you defined named groups that do not capture any chars, just empty strings. `(?<foo>)` matches and captures an empty string. Now, `\\t` in your pattern matches a literal backslash followed with the letter `t`. So, `~r/(?<foo>\\t)/` will find a match in a `~S(2018-06-16T07:03:23.813056Z\thello)` (a `2018-06-16T07:03:23.813056Z\thello` string that has no tab in it).

Besides, if you build a regex using a constructor from a string literal, you may define a tab in two ways, both as `"\t"` and `"\\t"`. The former one will be passed to the regex engine as a literal TAB char while in the latter case the regex escape consisting of a literal `\` and `t` will be passed matching the same TAB chars. `Regex.compile!("(?<foo>\t)")` = `Regex.compile!("(?<foo>\\t)")`.

You can actually match the non-tab chunks, perhaps, with `[^\t]*`:

```
~r/(?<foo>[^\t]*)\t(?<hello>[^\t]*)\t(?<world>[^\t]*)/
          ^^^^^^            ^^^^^^            ^^^^^^
```

If you want to match that pattern as whole string only, enclose with `^` and `$`:

```
~r/^(?<foo>[^\t]*)\t(?<hello>[^\t]*)\t(?<world>[^\t]*)$/
   ^                                                  ^
```

The `[^\t]*` is a negated character class matching any char but a tab, 0 or more times (`*` is a greedy quantifier that matches 0 or more consecutive occurrences of the quantified subpattern).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ltky4T).

Comment: What would happend if you had a string with a named value which in that case is empty? like "2018-06-16T07:03:23.813056Z\t\tworld", you would have two \t, could you map that value into %{"hello" => ""} somehow?

Comment: @lapinkoira Isn't it what you already get? See [this demo](http://rextester.com/CAUHJ69465). `[^\t]*` matches ***0*** or more chars other than tabs.

Comment: mm it should work then yes, I am probably having a different issue then

Comment: Ok, share a fiddle if you need more help.

Comment: awesome thanks, gonna try to fix it first and if I cant get it through I share a fiddle